# content in div is not showing

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm getting a blank webpage and I don't understand why. I noticed that if i put a `'<p'` (yes, without the closing `'>'`) after `'<div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-white">'` in scratchpad everything works.

```
<html>
    <title>rand</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway"/>
    <body>
        <div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-white">
            <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding-large w3-xlarge">
                Logo
            </div>
            <div class="w3-display-middle">
                <h1 class="w3-jumbo w3-animate-top">COMING SOON</h1>
                <hr class="w3-border-grey rando"/>
                <p class="w3-large w3-center">35 days left</p>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-padding-large">
                Powered by <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">w3.css</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you hotlinking your CSS from W3schools?

Comment: Also, this code DOES indeed run, all of the text is white, however. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVojQo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> w3-text-white

This CSS class is making your text appear white on white.

> w3-display-bottomleft

This CSS class is making your div appear outside the container: the container has a height of 0, since its children are all positioned `absolute`ly.  Since the above class has `bottom: 0`, the div is being rendered above the container.

Comment: Theres supposed to be an image in the background. thats what 'bmimg' is in the first div.

Comment: @ProjectPC `div`s are not scaled according to the dimensions of their background.  Perhaps this is where the confusion lies.  If you specify the `div`'s dimensions explicitly and remove the `w3-text-white` CSS class, you will see the background and the `div`'s content appear as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by removing "w3-display-container" and replacing it with si_ze which has the property of `position: absolute;`.